# excessive whitespace generated in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When the viewport is resized smaller, excessive whitespace appears between the slider and line of text. I don't see what is causing this except it appears to relate to the font-size in the @media tags. I have temporary set all the margins:0 but the problem persists. I'm hoping someone can through some light on this.

I couldn't see how to boil this down to  jsFiddle so please go to a beta site at - www.pricelearman.com/clients/serenaconstruction. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looking at your beta site you are not using bootstrap correctly.  You have `container-fluid` on everything when you really only need it on your main page element.  It should be your outer most wrapper.  Next you should remove the full-width stuff, after you get rid of the extra containers you'll see the white space lessens.

Comment: Take a look at the bootstrap docs to see how each component should be structured.  For instance there is no need to have a navbar and a mobile-menu, the navbar will take care of mobile for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your #homeSlider css, you can remove the height attribute. the height can be dependent on the child element.